# Grails w/ Spring Security Core only allowing owner to update in GSP

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143354/grails-access-only-for-objects-owner) has some code to add to the controller closure, which is fine, but what if I want to use the grails default scaffolding views but only have the edit/update buttons appear if the user is a manager, or the domain object is owned by the user? [Reading the documentation](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html), I've tried:

```
<sec:access expression="hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER') || (projectInstance.owner == springSecurityService.currentUser)">
   <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" /></span>
</sec:access>
```

But the access class doesn't seem to allow ORs:

```
Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <sec:access>: Cannot handle (124) '|'
```

Anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've decided that would be stupid. A better approach is to do it in the controller as:

```
 def edit = {
    def projectInstance = Project.get(params.id)
    def managerOrAdmin = SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted('ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_MANAGER')
    def editable = (projectInstance.owner == springSecurityService.currentUser
                   || managerOrAdmin)
    if (!projectInstance) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'project.label', default: 'Project'), params.id])}"
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    else {
        return [projectInstance: projectInstance, editable:editable]
    }
}
```

and then in the gsp do

```
<g:if test="${editable}">
  <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" /></span>
</g:if>
```

which makes sense, if we follow the good programming mantra of "views should do as little processing logic as possible in MVC"

Comment: I agree with this approach since your expression is slightly more complex than a simple role check.

Comment: If I need this in several actions, I wonder if it's better to use beforeUpdate method in the object?